# Python director listing error, class

Tags: python, class, listdir

```
import os
class sortare:
    dictionar = raw_input("Scrie calea catre director: ")
    lista = lista.os.listdir(dicionar)
    def __init__(self):
        for item in lista:
            print item
            print len(item)
```

I learn python, and i create a class that list file/dir on a director.

Where is the wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your entire code, but generally you're supposed to put _all_ your class initialization code inside the `__init__` method. Your `dictionar =` and `lista =` lines may be in the wrong place.

Comment: i try in diferit method, but i don't know verry well class method(working learn), i tri in this mode: http://pastebin.com/hku285qV

Comment: You usually shouldn't return a value inside a `for` loop, since that causes the loop to terminate immediately. And in any case, you're not allowed to return anything from inside an `__init__` method at all. Why not try using a regular function instead of a class?

Comment: Regular function work good, but i want to learn about class; anyway, can i get a good example to work with class? Or what i do wrong here.
 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

class sortare:
    def __init__(self):
        dictionar = raw_input("Scrie calea catre director: ")
        lista = lista.os.listdir(dicionar)
        for item in lista:
            print item
            print len(item)

sortare_object = sortare()
```

You created a class. To run `__init__` method you need to create an object of that class. That's why I added `sortare_object = sortare()` line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the the mistake you are making is the difference in variable name, first you used "dictionar" and then used "dicionar" use either of them.

Apart from that I guess the issue you are facing is that the variables inside the class are not global, to solve the issue what you can do is to declare the variables as global like below:

```
   import os
   class sortare:
       global dictionar, lista
       dictionar = raw_input("Scrie calea catre director: ")
       lista = os.listdir(dictionar)
       def __init__(self):

           lista = os.listdir(dictionar)
           for item in lista:
               print item
               print len(item)
```

But this is not the right way of writing the code, you should either ask for input argument outside and then pass just the "lista" as arguments to the function or you can add both asking input and calculating the lista in init.

Method 1:

```
   import os
   class sortare:

       def __init__(self, lista):

           for item in lista:
               print item
               print len(item)


   dictionar = raw_input("Scrie calea catre director: ")
   lista = os.listdir(dictionar)
   sortare(lista)
```

Method 2:

```
   import os
   class sortare:


       def __init__(self):
           dictionar = raw_input("Scrie calea catre director: ")
           lista = os.listdir(dictionar)
           for item in lista:
               print item
               print len(item)

   sortare(lista)
```